# File security when device is locked and background fetch in iOS7

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, nsfilemanager

I am using file security using NSFileProtectionKey attribute like this:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:@{NSFileProtectionKey : NSFileProtectionComplete} ofItemAtPath:coreDataFilePath error:NULL];
```

So, no file in that path can be opened when device is passcode locked. The problem is that from iOS7 Apps can run in the background even while device is locked. When running like that  Coredata `[NSManagedObjectContext save:]` will fail with error:

> NSCocoaErrorDomain, 134030, The operation couldnâ€™t be completed.
>   (Cocoa error 134030.) { NSSQLiteErrorDomain =
>   23; NSUnderlyingException = "Updating max pk failed: authorization
>   denied"; }

How to handle such case?

Answer (score 10):

First, see Session 204 "What's New with Multitasking" from the WWDC 2013 videos. It covers this case.

There are several approaches you can take, in order of security preference:

- Write the data to another location (using `NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen`) until the device is unlocked, then merge. This is generally the preferred approach.
- Set your main database to `NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen` and keep it open.
- Set your database to `NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication`. This is generally the worst approach.

Comment: Regarding "Write the data to another location (using NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen) until the device is unlocked, then merge. This is generally the preferred approach." How do you store the data that is to be written to core data until the user decides to unlcok the device.

Comment: Either by writing the network format (often JSON). Or serializing the objects with NSCoding. In either case, by saving to a file until Core Data is unlocked.

Comment: Doesn't saving a raw file to disk create another risk for application security. Anyway do you have any suggestions regarding how to detect if core data is unlocked.

Comment: The new file will be encrypted if NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen is set. You can create new encrypted files while locked. You can check the protection status through UIApplication protectedDataAvailable.